# How to do exception handling in spark jdbc savemode.overwrite?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a spark job which writes to postgres db . I am currently using savemode.overwrite with truncate= true.
Hence, whenever the spark job will run,it will truncate the table and write the data.

I wanted to know when doing insert overwrite,is there a possibility that a spark job failure may cause the data to be truncated but not insert?

I am trying to make sure that if the spark job fails , I do not end up with having an empty table .

Comment: You could save your dataframe as hive table, so even if your spark job fails you can populate the table with data from the hive table by running it again

Comment: Yea that is one option. But I wanted to know if there is any safe mechanism in spark jdbc to handle this scenario